# JVM crash on Tesseract.getWords API invocation running with ubuntu docker image

Tags: docker, crash, jvm, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to extract words from image using tess4j. When I invoke getWords API then JVM crashes in some case.

Following are the versions for relevant packages/software

- Java version: 11
- Tomcat version: 8.5
- Relevant java dependencies

  ```
  <dependency> 
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId> 
      <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId> 
      <version>4.3.1</version> 
  </dependency> 
  <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId> 
      <artifactId>tesseract-platform</artifactId> 
      <version>4.0.0-1.4.4</version> 
  </dependency>
  ```

Followings are my observation

1. If I run the same setup on my fedora (version 29) desktop it works fine.
2. If I run inside docker with the same setup but with the base image as ubuntu:18.04, then on extraction of words from image JVM crashes.
3. Please note that env TESSDATA_PREFIX is set appropriately. Also I tried by setting LC_ALL=C  but no luck if I run with docker image.

Crash report from catalina.out

```
contains_unichar_id(unichar_id):Error:Assert failed:in file ../ccutil/unicharset.h, line 513
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1fe7aa369b, pid=40, tid=89
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.2+9) (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libtesseract.so.4+0x25969b]  ERRCODE::error(char const*, TessErrorLogCode, char const*, ...) const+0x16b
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h %e" (or dumping to /app/identity-service/core.40)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /app/identity-service/hs_err_pid40.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

One of thread the had problem from thread dump

```
Current thread (0x00007f210015a800):  JavaThread "fb5c080c-25bb-494a-8e6d-1df6df91c188" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=89, stack(0x00007f206e7d2000,0x00007f206e8d3000)]

Stack: [0x00007f206e7d2000,0x00007f206e8d3000],  sp=0x00007f206e8cdbb0,  free space=1006k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libtesseract.so.4+0x25969b]  ERRCODE::error(char const*, TessErrorLogCode, char const*, ...) const+0x16b

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Lcom/sun/jna/Function;JI[Ljava/lang/Object;)I+0
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;ZI)Ljava/lang/Object;+211
j  com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+271
j  com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+344
j  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.TessBaseAPIRecognize(Lnet/sourceforge/tess4j/ITessAPI$TessBaseAPI;Lnet/sourceforge/tess4j/ITessAPI$ETEXT_DESC;)I+20
j  net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.getWords(Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;I)Ljava/util/List;+31
```

Can you please help?

Comment: The problem is not related to Java/JVM. See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1177

Answer (score 0):

Update:
This turned out to be memory issue